# How to push/pull/fetch different repositories which are belong to different user of BitBucket on one computer

Tags: git, bitbucket, tortoisegit

We have a repository in bit bucket for (office project where i am working). TortoiseGit client is set in my office laptop to use the git repository.

Now I have made my own bit bucket repository for home use (for my free lancing project at home). How can I set the username and password in TortoiseGit client for this new repository. I want to use the same TortoiseGit client for both the repositories without any issue. Credentials are already there in TortoiseGit for office project/repository. But TortoiseGit does not asking me the credentials to checkout (Git clone) for the new home project and failing to checkout.

The question simply means how to work with 2 different projects (2 repositories) simultaneously using TortoiseGit Client.

Comment: [TortoiseSVN](https://tortoisesvn.net/) is a Subversion (SVN) client. Perhaps you mean [TortoiseGit](https://tortoisegit.org/)? You have tagged both [tag:github] and [tag:bitbucket]; which are you using? You have also tagged your question with [tag:svn-repository]; are you working with Subversion repositories or Git repositories? And, finally, neither [tag:version-control] nor [tag:branching-and-merging] seems relevant here. **Please don't spam tags.** Use only the ones that are actually relevant to your question.

Comment: @Chris I have updated the question and tagging accordingly. Can you please answer and clarify things.

Comment: Do you use 2 user accounts of BitBucket? One is for office project and the other one is for your home use?

Comment: Yes yue Lin. That`s correc

Comment: Then, try SSH key.

Comment: How do i use this. Any specific step or screen shot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create/use N **SSH key** pairs for N BitBucket user accounts:

Open TortoiseGit Settings dialog, and Re-run First Start Wizard

[image]

Next, next, ..., to the following dialog.

Then, select `TortoiseGitPlink` and push the `Generate PuTTY key pair` button

[image]

Push `Generate` in PuTTY Key Generator dialog

[image]

Move your mouse till it finished

[image]

Copy the public key, key in the passphrase, save the private key.

[image]

Go BitBucket and view your profile

[image]

Add SSH key

[image]

Paste the public key you copied, and Add key

[image]

Go your BitBucket repository web page, and copy SSH URL

[image]

Go your local repository, open TortoiseGit Settings dialog, use SSH URL and the private key file

[image]

When you push/pull/fetch the first time, will popup:

[image]

Key in your passphrase, and push OK button. Then, will popup:

[image]

Push Yes button, so that Pegeant will be run

[image]

and cache your private key and your passphrase:

[image]

So that you don't need to key in passphrase again and again when push/pull/fetch.

Last thing: create/use another SSH for another BitBucket user account. :D

Comment: These images are not visible Yue

Comment: Thanks for all the efforts. I wil check it later on and correct it if it will help :)

Comment: i haven't check it yet. But it looks a good solution although long enough process.  I was waiting for other answer too but didn't received any  answer. thanks again for your effort. I am marking answer as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like SSH and still want to use https, then:

1. Go "Manage Your Credentials". Windows Start -> keyin "cred" -> click "Manage Your Credentials"

   [image]
2. Remove all credentials related to BitBucket, so that you can re-create the correct ones.

   [image]
3. Use the remote repository URL with user name

   [image]
   [image]
4. Re-Fetch and keyin the correct password for first BitBucket account

   [image]
5. do the same things(Step 3 & 4) with your second account